# Simple Log Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Fairly new to logs, stuck here:

The equation $y=4^{3x}$ can be written in terms of $x$:

$$y=4^{3x}$$
$$\log(y)=\log(4^{3x})$$
$$0=3x\log(4)-\log(y)$$
$$0=3x\log\bigg(\dfrac{4}{y}\bigg)$$

At this point I am totally stumped. I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: The last line is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotient rule of logarithms says that for any positive $b\ne 1$ and any positive $M,N$ we have $$\log_bM-\log_bN=\log_b\frac MN.$$ Note that this says *nothing* about differences of *multiples* of logarithms. The $3x$ is going to prevent you from bringing them together in that way. Instead, from $$3x\log 4=\log y,$$ we can simply divide through by $3\log 4$ to get $$x=\frac{\log y}{3\log 4}.$$

Here is another way to approach it. Given any positive $b\ne 1$ and any positive $t,$ we can think of $\log_bt$ as "the exponent on the base $b$ that yields $t$." That is, $\log_bt$ is the unique number $s$ such that $t=b^s.$ That means (for instance) that we can immediately rewrite $y=4^{3x}$ as $3x=\log_4 y,$ so that $$x=\frac13\log_4 y.$$ From there, we can use the change-of-base formula to rewrite it in terms of common logarithms, if we like, and get exactly the same result as above.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, however the answer is different. Is $x=\dfrac{1}{3}\log_{4}y$ the same as $x=\dfrac{\log_{4}y}{3}$ ?

Comment: $64=4^3$ hence $\log_{4}64=\log_{4}4^3=3$

Comment: @nitrous2: Keep in mind that dividing is the same as multiplying by the reciprocal in general. In particular, dividing by $3=\frac31$ and multiplying by $\frac13$ are the same thing.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The final step is not correct:

$$3x \log \left( \frac 4 y\right) = 3x \left(\log 4 - \log y\right) = 3x \log 4 - 3x \log y$$